# Automating CSV conversion from iso-8859-2 to utf-8

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

I have quite a few CSV files that are unfortunately encoded with iso-8859-2 (according to Brackets). I would like to iterate over these files with PHP and convert them.

I found https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/converter/charset/ but the way I can use the conversion function is uncertain to me.

Their example code

```
use League\Csv\CharsetConverter;

$csv = new SplFileObject('/path/to/french.csv', 'r');
$csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);

$encoder = (new CharsetConverter())->inputEncoding('iso-8859-15');
$records = $encoder->convert($csv);
```

This is my code so far that is part of a form to upload one file and save the contents to the database for testing. It of course saves the text in the incorrect format.

```
$db = ConnectDB::getConnection('address_dtb');

$sql = " ... ";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$rowCount = 0;

$temp_name = $_FILES['adresscsv']['tmp_name'];

$file_handle = fopen($temp_name, 'r');

while (($items = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {

    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }

    $stmt->execute($items);

    $rowCount++;

}

fclose($file_handle);

ConnectDB::closeConnection($db);
```

What is the correct way to use the PHP CSV library above to iterate over locally saved files in a `for` loop to automate the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use a library. There is a function in PHP that can do that [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `iconv` as hinted.

```
$files = glob('address/*.csv');

foreach ($files as $csv) {
    $file_data = file_get_contents($csv);
    $utf8_file_data = iconv('Windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $file_data);
    file_put_contents($csv, $utf8_file_data);
}
```